# jQuery scroll to anchor not working correctly

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have the the following link: http://www.alessandrosantese.com/test/aldemair-productions/project.html

and I am using this to scroll to a specific div with an id:

```
        $('.project-nav a').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var anchor = $(this).attr('data-id'),
            el = $('#' + anchor);
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: el.offset().top}, 500);

        });
```

it works almost right, it doesn't scroll at a correct location, they all seem to be incorrect.

If you click details you wil be scrolled just above cast for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: el.offset().top - $('header.close').height()}, 500);
```

The scrolling is working correctly. If you hide the header, you will see that 'Details' is perfectly at the top of the window...